# Matplotlib Graph not showing up on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am currently trying to graph data using Python3 and matplotlib. I am developing on OSx Sierra and when I run, it is not showing up. There are no errors returned. I included plt.show() in my code and it is definitely running. Any help to get this graph showing would be appreciated. Vanilla Python3, edited in Emacs, ran from both IDLE and terminal. Neither work. Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.show()
```

Does not produce anything, and there are no errors. I have tried 
    plt.switch_backend('MacOSX') and the error persists.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are other people with `osx` computers around, but we cannot help you if you don't show us what you have tried.

Comment: Try to add `%matplotlib inline`  at the beginning of your script.

Comment: IDLE says that is invalid syntax. Let me know if I did something wrong:    
    `%matplotlib inline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.show()`

Comment: Did you actually plot anything before `plt.show()`? Try inserting a `plt.plot([1,2,3])` before that.

Comment: If, for some reason, you just want an empty figure, you can also do `fig = plt.figure()` instead of the `plot` command. Anyway, you need to create a figure in some way, otherwise `matplotlib` has nothing to show to you.

Comment: You're right. In my sample plt.plot() did the trick, and the reason that I'm not seeing anything in my real project is because it's traversing along a 10,000 entry CSV. That explains the 'endless loading'. Problem resolved! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to wrap up the comments into an answer: `pyplot.show()` only produces a figure, if a figure has been created. This can be done explicitly by stating

```
fig = plt.figure()
```

or implicitly by plotting something (the figure is then created in the background), e.g.

```
plt.plot([1,2,3])
```

once `plt.show()` is called, all currently active figures will be displayed on the screen.